# Get predictions from Keras/Tensorflow once model is trained

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I am working on a project involving neural machine translation (translating English to French).

I have worked through some examples online, and have now finished the model. Once a model is trained using Keras, how do I then get a prediction of a translation without training the entire model again, because with the large dataset I am using, each epoch takes some time and of course, I can't train the model every time I want a translation.

So what is the correct way of then generating predictions on new inputs without training the whole model again?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should add some code, because here you have people guessing what your code does.

Comment: Hi there, I have added some pictures. As can be seen in the first, I saved my model as "saved_weight.hdf5", and I then load them into "modelPred". Then in the "translate" function, I use the predict function but get the error above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your model the model and its weights when the fit ends using :

```
keras.model.save(model_name)
```

At any time, you can load your trained model using

```
model = keras.load(model_name)
```

then perform predictions as

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: Hi there, I have implemented your feedback,  as can be seen in the first picture, I saved my model as "saved_weight.hdf5", and I then load them into "modelPred". Then in the "translate" function, I use the predict function but get the error above

Comment: You are saving only the weights into "saved_weights.hdf5" file, in stead of that, please consider the use of model.save("my_model") that saves the previously trained model (architecture and weights) into a folder called `my_model`. After that you can load it using modelPred = keras.load('my_model')

Comment: I got the error "module 'keras' has no attribute 'load'"

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention it should be keras.models.load_model('my_model')

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.predict()` function which you can pass new inputs into it and it give you a prediction. The docs for this function are here: [keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, so let's say I run the code and it trains the model, how do I know the model is saved, and how do I use that prediction function on the saved model? Thanks

Comment: after the training you can run `model_name.save(filepath)` where the model name is the name of your model and the filepath is where the model is saved too. In the python script it will keep the weights of your model until you close the file or rerun it. [This](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model) is the tf keras documentation on how to save a model and then load it. You should just be able to go model_name.predict() and it will run with the model you trained.